# Fetch GitLab Projects

Tags: java

I'm making a simple website where the user can see which repositories exist on the gitlab.

**My question is:** Is there a way to check which projects exist on Gitlab and retrieve the names/branches?

For example: Go to gitlab.company.com and check the projects.

Comment: check github api https://developer.github.com/v3/

Comment: I'm using GitLab, not GitHub. Is it the same?

Comment: Nope, missread, sorry. Check GitLab API instead haha https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/README.html

Comment: Can I integrate this using Java?

Comment: They have REST APIs, you can use any of your favourite language to talk to those APIs.

Answer (score 0):

You could use GitLab4J (https://github.com/gmessner/gitlab4j-api).  It provides an easy to use Java API for talking with a GitLab server.  Here's a quick snippet to pull down a list of projects from gitlab.com:

```
// Create a GitLabApi instance to communicate with gitlab.com
GitLabApi gitLabApi = new GitLabApi("https://gitlab.com", "YOUR_PRIVATE_TOKEN");

// Get the list of projects your account has access to
List<Project> projects = gitLabApi.getProjectApi().getProjects();
```

Comment: Thanks. My only problem atm is that the Gitlab API uses a FasterXML and keeps giving me a lot of errors.

Comment: GitLab4J-API is thoroughly tested.  If you are trying to use it you must include it as a dependency in your build definition.  Are you using mvn or gradle?  If so there are instructions on how to set the dependency at:
https://github.com/gmessner/gitlab4j-api